# Open multiple files in order in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows XP, when you selected multiple files in Explorer, then chose an app from the context menu (Open With, etc.), that app would open the selected files in the selected order.  In Windows 7, it doesn't seem to do this.  It opens them in an unpredictable order.  How can I select multiple files in Windows 7 Explorer in such a way that when I open them, they will open in a predictable order?

Comment: Weird - I tried it out a few time and it seemed pretty random, but I believe it may have something to do with how the windows were opened in the past / what order they were in.. not sure though.

Comment: perhaps it's related to optimization? some files may be large and consequently incur a deal of system load.

Comment: Note: I ran CCleaner and cleaned Window Size/Location cache, etc, and it still seemed kinda random - I don't think it's what @WikiWiz said because I've been opening the same four files (different sizes, contents, etc) and the order keeps changing - I figured it would be consistent if it had something to do with optimization, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @WikiWiz: It still happens even if I'm opening multiple files of exactly the same size.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I found is to open multiple files within the app, not within the explorer. Tried this with notepad and adobe reader, multiple txt and pdf is in random order when open in explorer, but always sorted by name, size, date or whatever i sorted them in "Open" dialog window if I open multiple files through "File" > "Open"  menu in app. Hope this workaround will be helpful.